# Calculating Column Totals from Matrix - C Programming

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, sum, percentage

As the title implies I am having some serious trouble getting the column totals and percentages to calculate in this program. I have spent several hours extracting code and trying to implement incrementally but have failed miserably. `C` is not my strong suit.

The program should be able to do the following:

a. Display the table with appropriate labels for the rows and columns.

b. Compute and display the total number of votes received by each candidate and the percentage of the total votes cast.

c. If any one candidate received over 50 percent of the votes, the program should display a message declaring that candidate the winner.

d. If no candidate received 50 percent of the votes, the program should display a message declaring a runoff between the two candidates receiving the highest number of votes; the two candidates should be identified by their letter names.

e. Run the program once with the data shown and once with candidate C receiving only 108 votes in Precinct 4.

My program adds the row totals and prints them for the "Total" column. I am trying to figure out how to add the column totals and pass it to the "Total" column for each candidate.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int votes[5][4]={
      192,48,206,37,
      147,90,312,21,
      186,12,121,38,
      114,21,408,39,
      267,13,382,29};

   char cand[4]={'A','B','C','D'};

   int row_totals[5];
   int col_totals[4];

   int total_votes;

   float percent[5];

   int row,col;


   int total=0;
   for(row=0;row<=4;row++)
   {
      row_totals[row]=0;

      for(col=0;col<=3;col++)
      {
         row_totals[row] += votes[row][col];
         total+=votes[row][col];
      }
   }

   printf("          Candidate     Candidate   Candidate    Candidate   Total   Percent\n");
   printf(" Precinct      A            B           C            D\n");

   for(row=0;row<=4;row++)
   {
      printf("%6d",row+1);
      for(col=0;col<=3;col++)
      {
         printf("%12d",votes[row][col]);
      }
      printf("%11d",row_totals[row]);
      percent[row]=(double)(row_totals[row]*100)/total;
      printf("\t%.2f\n",percent[row]);

   }


   int i;
   double first=percent[0];
   double sec=percent[0];
   int maxVal,second_big;
   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
      if(first>percent[i])
      {
         first=percent[i];
         maxVal=i;
      }


   }
   int j;
   for(j=0;j<4;j++)
   {
      if(percent[j]>sec && percent[j]!=sec)
      {
         sec=percent[j];
         second_big=j;
      }

   }
   if(first>50)
   {
      printf("%c is the winner.\n",cand[maxVal]);
   }

   else if(sec<=50)
   {
      printf("%c and %c are in a runoff.\n",cand[maxVal],cand[second_big]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("c is the winner.\n",cand[maxVal]);` - that should be `%c` at the start. Anyway, what exactly is your problem? What values are you seeing printed out and what do you expect?

Comment: My program adds the row totals and prints them for the "Total" column. I am trying to figure out how to add the column totals and pass it to the "Total" column for each candidate.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (row = 0; row <= 4; row++)
{
    printf("%6d", row + 1);
    for (col = 0; col <= 3; col++)
    {
        printf("%12d", votes[row][col]);
    }
    printf("%11d", row_totals[row]);
    percent[row] = (row_totals[row] * 100) / total;
    printf("\t%.2f\n", percent[row]);

}
```

Here, you are processing 5 elements `0...4` but `percent` is only defined to have 4 elements `0...3`.

```
    double percent[4];
```

Either change the condition for the loop to `<=3` or increase the size of the `percent` array.